# How to add new element 'NEW' to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How to add new element `'NEW'` to numpy array `features`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled)
df['NEW'] = minutes
features = np.append(features, 'NEW', 1)
df.to_excel("A.xls", header=features[sorted_idx],index=False)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work with pandas and the exporting to excel, but you can try : `np.column_stack((features,df['NEW']))`.

Comment: @Divakar: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: You need to use some kind of concatenation depending on the shapes of the inputs (features and 'NEW') you are looking to concatenate.

Comment: Does `features[sorted_idx]` have the same amount of items as the number of columns of `df`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `features` is a 1D array of strings. Then you could do:

```
features =np.append(features,['New'])
```

But if you just want the header of your DataFrame as an array this is probably better:

```
features = df.columns.values
```